# Create many to many objects inline simirly to inlinetabular for admin

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to allow users to create inline/on-the-fly an object of model A that has a many to many relationship with a field of a model B, while creating an object B...basically just like TabularInline allows you to do on the admin.

Answer (score 0):

okay this will help you
models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    fileds of A

class B(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    a= models.ForeignKey('Voyage',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

form.py add this :

```
inlineForm = inlineformset_factory(A,B,
      fields=('name'),
      can_delete=False,extra=4,max_num=4        
      )
```

views.py :

```
from .form import inlineForm

def test(request,id):
    obj=A.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= inlineForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('core:simple'))
    form = inlineForm(instance=obj)
    return render(request,'obj/inlineForm.html',{'formset':form})
```